# Calculating Characteristic Impedance of Jumper Wire

Tags: signal, differential, characteristic-impedance

I'm conducting a test of the LTC490 driver/receiver (http://www.analog.com/media/en/technical-documentation/data-sheets/490fb.pdf), using a small incremental encoder.

I'll make the connections using jumper wires. In this case, is it necessary to use a terminating resistor - I would imagine the resistance of a jumper wire of a small distance is negligible? Nevertheless, how would I go about calculating the characteristic impedance of a wire, given length and thickness?

Side Note: Some of the wiring diagrams include a capacitor between the two lines. What is its purpose, and when is it necessary to use one?

Comment: Embed the circuit into your question.

Answer (score 1):

Impedance is  \$Z_o=\sqrt{L/C}\$ with twisted pair being about 220 ohms with tolerance depending on wire radius~gap and 30~40 twists per meter.

For just a wire with a large air gap dielectric  C drops and Z rises , with L being about 0.5~1uH/m. So signal reflections start to be noticeable as ringing  when length of jumper >5~10%\$\lambda\$.